# Java: Read file from specific point till end of line

Tags: java, file, readline, filereader, fromcharcode

How do I read a file from a specified position to the end of that line.

Example:

File Contents:

```
01234567
f1=value
f2=value
f3=value
```

01234567 = character position.
I want it to start reading the line from the "v" in value and I want it to read till the end of the line.
So the position would be 3.

Answer (score 0):

Run your text file through `colrm` first. Or, when reading each line pragmatically, use `String.substring`.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [FileInputStream.skip](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#skip%28long%29)

If that doesn't work, you could try reading *n* bytes from the stream to put at the start read position (preferably via blocks instead of a byte at a time)